# Receiving information Bluetooth devices using an Android App

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, droidscript

I would like to know if you can send/recieve information from a Bluetooth device such as a headset or something of the sort. As well as if this is possible using JavaScript. The app I use to code JavaScript is called "DroidScript", which allows you to make apps using JavaScript and HTML.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html

Comment: How are you using JavaScript in an Android app?

Comment: @soana I use Droidscript, it is a free app for coding apps using JavaScript, as well as HTML.

Comment: you should edit this into your question and explain it more carefully using the little edit link below the tag buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DroidScript then you will probably need to create a DroidScript plugin in Java (assuming DroidSCript does not already do what you want).

Note: The latest alpha version of DroidScript can generate template AIDE projects for creating DroidScript plugins.